# Is there options how to code/create SharePoint lists and pages using SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-list, sharepointframework

I developed SPFx web-part client-side solution using the SharePoint framework. I successfully create a list with some columns (it's the list's columns, not the site). But now, I need to create lookup columns and pages under site pages and add the current app to that page, so are there any options, on how to code for the same using SharePoint framework and a web-part client-side solution? Have anybody some ideas or documentation which could help me to move further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SP PnP JS for creating new SharePoint lists or site pages in SharePoint online site using SPFx code.

Check below official documentations which has example codes for creating list or site pages:

1. [Create SharePoint List](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#add-list)
2. [Create SharePoint Site Pages](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/clientside-pages/#create-a-new-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a custom SharePointlist in spfx, here are the official ui and code for your reference:
[image]
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist

For questions about the lookup column, you can refer to this link:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301286/sharepoint-framework-create-a-lookup-column-using-feature

Sincerely hope these can help you